# Can I use Pytesseract and OpenCV to scan PNG iPhone text messages using Python 3.8 on Visual Studio?

Tags: opencv, python-3.8, python-tesseract

I only get the output of a Python executable saying starting script, checking image png, and then script complete. Then enter any key to continue. My desired output would be for this to scan the png and output each screenshot (.png file) in the specified directory, extract the text from the screenshots using Tesseract OCR, and then print the extracted text to the terminal or command prompt, categorized by the texter ("You" or "Other Texter").

```
import os
import cv2
import pytesseract

print("Starting script...")

# Specify the path to the Tesseract executable
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

# Define the directory path
directory_path = r'C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\Convo'

# Loop through all PNG files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    print(f"Checking file: {filename}")
    if filename.endswith('.png'):
        print(f"Processing file: {filename}")
        image_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        
        # Convert the image to the HSV color space
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        
        # Define the color ranges
        # Define blue color range in HSV
        lower_blue = (90, 50, 50)
        upper_blue = (130, 255, 255)

        # Define grey color range in HSV
        lower_grey = (0, 0, 150)
        upper_grey = (180, 25, 220)

        
        # Create masks for each color range
        blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
        grey_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_grey, upper_grey)
        
        # Extract and classify text
        for mask, texter in [(blue_mask, "You"), (grey_mask, "Other Texter")]:
            contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            for contour in contours:
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi)
                print(f"{texter}: {text}")
        
        # Print a message after processing each screenshot
        print(f"Processed {filename}")

print("Script completed.")
```

Comment: can you share an example of the image that you want to process?

Answer (score 0):

This was from a while ago. But I figured it out. I had to use a Python virtual environment, install all of the libraries. Insert the 500+ images into the desired code line, and then run it and output it into a .txt file. It was just old text messages between me and my mom. I gathered all of the most used words using Python and output them into a picture. But I also have them saved onto a text file as well as was able to read the sentiment, subjectivity, word count, message count, and other characteristics of the text.